# MS SQL - sum then divide by count

Tags: sql-server, count, sum, partition

I have written the following `SQL` query which provides the `total` number of days per employee.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  ([Entered_By]),
  SUM(ALL DATEDIFF(DAY, Time_End_UTC, Date_Entered_UTC)) OVER (PARTITION BY entered_by) AS Days

FROM [dbo].[Time_Entry]
WHERE date_start BETWEEN '06-01-2015' AND '06-30-2015'
AND DATEDIFF(DAY, Time_End_UTC, Date_Entered_UTC) > 2
```

I can also change "`sum`" to "`count`" (and remove the "`all`") and get a total number of records.

However I need one of the following:

1. a column with sum and another with count (*keep in mind that I can't write to this database*) OR
2. a column with the sum multiplied by the count

When I try to have both `(option 1)`, I run into issues.  And I can't figure out how to get the `multiplication` `(option 2)` to work.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you need to divide sum by count (as stated in your title) or multiply (as stated in your text)?

Answer (score 2):

I feel like this would be much easier to achieve with a `GROUP BY` query instead of a windowed `sum`:

```
Select [Entered_By]
,sum(datediff(Day, Time_End_UTC, Date_Entered_UTC))
,count(*) --count of all records in the group, which you could also multiply by the sum if you prefer option 2

From [dbo].[Time_Entry]
where date_start between '06-01-2015' and '06-30-2015'
and datediff(DAY, Time_End_UTC, Date_Entered_UTC) >2
GROUP BY [Entered_By] --this takes care of the distinctness of [Entered_By] and partitioning you had in your original query
```

Comment: Thanks.  That's great!  I did originally attempt this but must of messed it up in a revision somewhere.  You have been a great help - Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

For option 2, you can just

```
SELECT COUNT(ATTRIB) * SUM(ATTRIB) FROM TABLE;
```

Comment: I did try this in my original code without success but with the other comments, I got it working.  Thanks for the input.